# Are there sites hosting fossil repositories?

Tags: version-control, hosting, fossil

A given source-code management system is most useful to the developer community if there are good quality providers of repository hosting, and for open-source development it essential that this hosting is free and unencumbered. All the well-established version control systems have such providers, generally offering free provision of world-readable repositories and paid subscriptions for private repository hosting. For example:

- Git has the Microsoft-backed [Github](http://github.com/); additionally [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) provides not only rival hosting, but also makes the core implementation of its service available on an open-source basis
- Bazaar has [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/)
- Mercurial has [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/)

Are there similar providers allowing [Fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/) repositories to be hosted for free?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for Fossil currently has a section answering this question, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_(software)#Source_code_hosting - be warned that sections that are lists of links to enterprises are at risk of being culled, since they carry the risk of attracting spammy outfits.

Answer (score 34):

I just launched a fossil hosting solution over at http://chiselapp.com
It's still in alpha but supports a number of things already. Feel free to let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't figure how to send feedback from the site, so putting it here: the long registration form and needing yet another password immediately makes the site feel ancient and is a significant barrier to entry these days. Why does the site need my first or last names anyway? OpenID support would make it much easier to register.

Answer (score 5):

It seems Fossil is available on Sourceforge:
http://tkoutline.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/fossil/wiki

Though it's not clear if this is an official installation. It's within SF.net allowance to host custom CGI scripts, but a admin maintained installation would be nicer.

Even though setting up a Sourceforge entry is probably overkill for small projects (what Fossil targets), this seems a sensible project hosting option. If Fossil is not officially supported, we should lobby for it to become that. Most likely BerliOS would adopt it, too.

Answer (score 4):

This Site gives you a Free Fossil Repository hostet on Sourceforge:

http://fossilrepos.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2):

I dont know of any, but its so easy to set up your own on any  bit of hosting space you have access to that its less important than for other scm tools.

Link here to a tutorial I wrote on setting it up.

http://write.intellectualmollusc.net/2010/01/setting-up-a-fossil-repository-on-a-public-shared-server/

Comment: Thanks, your howto just mirrors the solution from the official fossil documentation, which I'm aware of. My question implies no personal hosting at all, hence me asking about a public site.