# Git backups: can I copy a git bare repository while it's being pushed to?

Tags: git

At our firm, we're experimenting with moving from svn to git. We want to make this simple for teams, while not burdening the sysadmins too much.

We've found a way to do this by making a bare repository on a (Windows) network drive that each team has, and push/pull to/from that. Authentication is arranged through file access permissions, so no need to set up https and the whole auth stuff. Great! (and we can access the drive remotely via VPN, so it's really almost as good as a https or git+ssh solution)

Better yet, we'll even get backups for free, because the network share is already being backed up. However, this backup runs rather unpredictably (backup up lasts several hours, so might continue onto the next working day).

Thus, it is possible that the drive is being backed up *while* a developer is pushing to the repository. With SVN, this could cause problems, which is why `svn hotcopy` exists.

Does the same risk exist with git? Can I copy a bare repository somewhere while someone is pushing to it? Naturally, it's all right if the push-being-done cannot be restored. It's also fine if some work has to be done to restore a backup that was made while it was pushed to (i.e. by removing the half-done push residue data). But if the entire bare repository becomes broken and unusable, then that's a problem.

I've done some experiments and couldn't see problems, but this does not mean that there can't be any.

**Edit:** I accepted a 'do it the right way' answer, because that's what I intend doing in the long run. For now, however, for us a simple solution has been to `git clone` the entire bare repository (onto the same drive) about an hour *before* the automated backup kicks in. The automated backup may incorrectly copy the "real" repository if it has been in use at that point, but it will not have trouble with the recently cloned copy. We know when the backup starts, just not when it ends, so that's good enough for us.

Comment: If you use raw copy you may have some branches locked (theoretically). You should prefer "git clone --bare" instead. I'm not sure how "git clone --bare" behaves if it meets a locked reference (if it waits for unlocking, fails, ignores the lock or skips the branch -- only first two options are safe).

Comment: I realise that some variation of `git clone` would probably be best. The point is, a standard file-copy backup mechanism (for the entire drive, not just the git repos) is *already in place*. My question is whether that one is safe enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be worth changing your backup policy to ignore backing up the whole Git repository and instead backup a [`Git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle). From [Git's Little Bundle of Joy](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/10/bundles.html):

> The bundle command will package up everything that would normally be pushed over the wire with a git push command into a binary file that you can email or sneakernet around, then unbundle into another repository.

This approach is also discussed in [Backup of github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo) and [Backup a Local Git Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository).

A quick test of a local repo reveals the following creates a single file that contains everything one would typically want in a full repo backup:

```
$ git bundle create ../my.bundle --all
```

Creating a clone from the bundle file is simply:

```
$ git clone my.bundle my-repo
```

Using `git ls-remote my.bundle` shows that all tags and branches are in the bundle.

However, to backup things that are probably not in the bundle file (like configuration, hooks, grafts, alternates, etc.), I would take the backup a few steps further and backup the [Git repository](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout) (short the `objects`, `refs` and `logs` directories) and the bundle file (the contents of the `objects` and `refs` repository directories are in the bundle and not needed). Unless the bundle does contain these files; then you only need to backup the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

How do you deal with other files what could be modified during backup procedure?

If you handle this situation already, you could use the same approach here. Otherwise you might get broken files anywhere, either in git, or in svn, or even in bare TXT.